# Gson custom deserializing logic based on field name

Tags: android, gson

My class is like:

```
class Foo {
   public String duration;
   public String height;
}
```

And my json data looks like

```
{"duration":"12200000", "height":"162"}
```

Now I want to deserialize it by

```
 Foo foo = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, Foo.class);
```

So that, 
     foo.duration is "20 mins" (number of minutes),
     foo.height is "162cm"

Is this possible to do using Gson?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean under "deserialize"?

Comment: I meant,  Foo foo = gson.fromJson(...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GSON allows creation of custom deserializers/serializers. Try to read [here](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserializ).

Sorry for without an example.

```
class FooDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Foo>{
   @Override
   public Foo deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
   JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    JsonObject jo = (JsonObject)json;
    String a = jo.get("duration").getAsString()+" mins";
    String b = jo.get("height").getAsString() + " cm";

//Should be an appropriate constructor
    return new Foo(a,b);
    }               
}
```

then:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Foo.class, foo.new FooDeserializer()).create();
```

and you should receive result as you wish it to get using `fromJson(...)`.

Comment: Yes, in that doc, the custom deserializer def is based on data type, in my example above, both field type are String, but I need different deserialization logic based on field name.

Comment: If you have to do custom parsing for each field of the object being parsed, it defeats the purpose of using Gson !