# GSON deserialize string to two integers

Tags: java, json, gson

I am in a situation where I have to parse the following JSON:

```
{ "maj:min": "8:80" }
```

I know that maj and min will always be of integer-type so the class I am parsing to has both these fields as integers:

```
public int maj;
public int min;
```

How can I get GSON to give the "maj:min" field special treatement and parse it accordingly while deserializing?

Comment: Can you change the json structure so that it is { "maj": 8, "min": 80 } ? This will be more readily parseable by GSON.

Comment: I have no control on how I receive the JSON.

Comment: How about a custom deserializer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165412/gson-custom-deserializing-logic-based-on-field-name)? It seems like a lot of work for this simple case, but should work.

Comment: Implement an appropriate `JsonDeserializer` that would split both keys and values raw values halves and compose the result pair. It's extremely easy. Or, as people prefer here -  just deserialize it as a `Map` and have fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build the model for your custom field :

```
public class CustomHour {

    public int maj;
    public int min;

    public CustomHour(int maj, int min) {
        this.maj = maj;
        this.min = min;
    }
}
```

Build the deserializer for this custom class :

```
public class CustomHourDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<CustomHour> {

    public CustomHour deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) {

        String[] data = json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString().split(":");
        int maj = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
        int min = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
        return new CustomHour(maj, min);
    }
}
```

Build your `Data` class that embed the custom field (with the field name) :

```
public class Data {

    @SerializedName("maj:min")
    public CustomHour hour;
}
```

Register `CustomHourDeserializer` as type adapter before deserializing :

```
String input = "{ \"maj:min\": \"8:80\" }";
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(CustomHour.class, new CustomHourDeserializer());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Data data = gson.fromJson(input, Data.class);
System.out.println("min : " + data.hour.min + " | max : " + data.hour.maj);
```

Comment: Nice! I receive everything value as a String, even tho some are always integers. Can you help me on how to parse these accordingly?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data input ?

Comment: e.g. { "size": "1000" } - but I could easily solve this by just using annotations on my class, e.g. @SerializedName("size") private int size; Thanks.